# Receive remote log on a Rsyslog server

Tags: linux, centos, configuration, rsyslog, logs

I'm currently sending logs to a rsyslog server (ironport proxy), the server receive udp packets on port 514.
I know because i check with tcpdump on the port 514 and i see so much syslog messages.

But the problem is, i can't redirect theses messages into a file. I tried a lot of things I saw on the web (and here too) but it doesn't work.
What is the proper way to do this ?
If somebody here know the answer to my problem  :roll:

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please read [how to accept answers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 3):

On the server receiving syslog messages, on UDP port 514, you would need to add the following configuration:

```
$ModLoad imudp
$UDPServerRun 514
$AllowedSender UDP, 10.42.0.0/15 127.0.0.1

$template RemoteStore, "/var/log/remote/%HOSTNAME%/%timegenerated:1:10:date-rfc3339%"
:source, !isequal, "localhost" -?RemoteStore
:source, isequal, "last" ~
```

Make sure you allowed the right senders (`replace 10.42.0.0/15`), restart rsyslog. Then, you'll find your remote logs in `/var/log/remote/$hostname/YYYY-MM-DD`.

---

In addition / CentOS specifics: there's a fair chance your firewall is enabled. If so, it may be dropping inbound traffic to UDP port 514. Check for your firewall status (`systemctl status firewall`). If enabled, try to add a rule.

```
# firewall-cmd --get-default-zone
public
# firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=514/udp
# firewall-cmd --permanent
# firewall-cmd --reload
```

You might want to check for SELinux. If enabled, make sure it [allows rsyslog to receive UDP traffic to port 514](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/System_Administrators_Guide/s1-configuring_rsyslog_on_a_logging_server.html).

Comment: Thank you, i already know theses lines except $AllowedSender. It still doesn't work .. i commented the last two lines and replaced by :star:dot:star: RemoteStore" and the directory was created but only with localhost logs

Comment: Do you have some firewall running on your instance? If so, make sure UDP:514 is opened. Do you have SElinux enabled on this instance? If so, make sure it allows UDP:514 as well. Are you sure rsyslog listens on UDP:514? Note that your local logs may be mentioning about discarding messages, or some reason not to listen, ...

Comment: It was SElinux ! i configured it with your link, thank you so much !

Answer (score 0):

I recently was scratching my head on this very same problem. I tried the two above suggestions from SYN - still no dice. :(

On RHEL 7 I finally found I needed to add an "ACCEPT" rule in **/etc/sysconfig/iptables**:

```
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m udp --dport 514 -j ACCEPT
```

This must appear before any "REJECT" rules in the file.  Once that was in place things were golden! :)